# Why are light rays expressed or generally shown as a sine wave?

Tags: waves, visible-light, mathematical-physics

Whether it be a YouTube video or book lights rays i.e(the visible specturm,uv  rays) are expressed as a sine wave. Why is it so?
What is the plot of its against? Why does it oscillate? Why does it have wavelength? Why does it have frequency ? Does light really travel as a sine wave?

Comment: Do these answer your question? [Why is electromagnetic wave (light) a sine wave?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/364388/145491), [Questions regarding light being depicted as a sine wave](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/723316/145491),[Why do we think of light as a wave?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30402/why-do-we-think-of-light-as-a-wave), [How to picture wave nature of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/524519/145491).